# Run tess4j project suddenly wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse, tess4j

I am referring to the project "https://github.com/mnadeem/ocr-tess4j-example", at the beginning of normal operation, suddenly being given a do not know how to solve? I tried to modify the eclipse jvm memory, but it seems no effect :(, or the project itself is not stable?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears one of the DLLs from this project is causing the JVM to crash.  So yes, it doesn't look like this library is stable.

Comment: First, thanks for your advice, and I suspect this is the problem, what is the best way to solve it?